# Cloning Ubuntu installation without needing a Grub2 reinstall?

Tags: grub2, software-recommendation, clone

Is there any software out there that would allow a Ubuntu Hard Drive to be cloned without needing to reinstall grub after installation?

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna  check out [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php). I use it for back up purposes, it is capable of  copying your whole drive or a specified partition to a specified location such as an usb thumb drive,another hdd, ssh, etc.

Comment: I have tried with Paragon and Acronis and you can do the same with both of those programs. The problem is when you copy the drive it requires you reinstall grub after it completes.

Comment: With clonezilla  I did not need to do any grub updates, unless the  kernel of the system is changed. But for my case I was mostly copying  back to its original place.